# What is the expected SRID value in Teradata ST_Geometry Methods?

Tags: srid, teradata

In Teradata database there's *SPATIAL_REF_SYS* table in *SYSSPATIAL* schema. In my Teradata production database the table lists 3,167 different Spatial Reference Systems (SRSs).

Now, it seems that Teradata Geospatial has its own numbering for specifying SRSs. Let's check the below query.

```
SELECT *
FROM SYSSPATIAL.SPATIAL_REF_SYS
WHERE AUTH_SRID=4326;
```

Result:

```
SRID  AUTH_NAME  AUTH_SRID  SRTEXT    
----  ---------  ---------  ----------- 
1619  EPSG            4326  (see below)
```

the content of SRTEXT above is:

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84",DATUM["WGS_1984",SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.01745329251994328]]
```

Now the question is:

1. Which one is the valid SRID expected in all ST_Geometry Methods that take SRID as their parameter (eg: ST_SRID, ST_Geometry constructors, ST_Transform): the one as in **SRID** or **AUTH_SRID** column?
2. Similarly, which one is the valid SRID expected in the TDGeoImport Command (the tool for loading geospatial data into Teradata database)? Also how to type it as SRS parameter (with "epsg:" or simply just the number? The example in *Setting a Spatial Index* in the PDF "*GeoServer_Teradata_v1.0*" [here](http://download.teradata.com/download/cdn/doc/extensibility/geospatial/geoserver/GeoServer_Teradata_v1.0.pdf) does not include SRID parameter during TDGeoImport.